# Beginning and end of words in sed and grep

Tags: regex, sed

I don't understand the difference between `\b` and `\<` in GNU sed and GNU grep. It seems to me `\b` can always  replace `\<` and `\\>` without changing the set of matching strings.

More specifically, I am trying to find examples in which `\bsomething` and `\\< something`
do not match exactly the same strings.

Same question for `something\b` and `something\\>`.

Thank you

Comment: Just different sets of regex conventions; they're equivalent, but spelled differently.

Comment: also please make sure you mark an answer as accepted. by this you will increase your credibility and people will put more effort into answering your questions

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I suspect that it very rarely makes a difference whether you use (the more common) `\b` or (the more specific) `\<` and `\>`, but I can think of an example where it would.  This is quite contrived, and I suspect that in most real-world regex use it wouldn't make a difference, but this should demonstrate that it at least *could* make a difference in some cases.

If I have the following text:

```
this is his pig
```

and I want to know if `/\bis\b/` matches, it wouldn't matter if I instead used `/\<is\>/` or I instead used `/\>is\</`

But what if my text was instead

```
is this his pig
```

There's no longer a word-final boundary before the 'is', only a word-initial boundary.  Using `/\bis\b/` matches, and of course `/\<is\>/` does too, but `/\>is\</` does not.

In real life, though, I think it is not common that you really need to be able to make this distinction, which is why (at least outside of sed) `\b` is the normal word boundary marker for regular expressions.

Comment: Just to add a bookmark: on OS X you'll need to use [[:<:]] and [[:>:]] for word boundary. Using \b or \< just doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks @PetrusRepo! That's handy to know.

Comment: Um, `/\>is\</` will never match, will it? `\>` matches if there's word character to the left and non-word one to the right. But we also expect to see `i` to the right, which is a word character.

Answer (score 9):

`\<` matches the transition from non-word to word.

`\>` matches the transition from word to non-word.

`\b` is equivalent to `(\<|\>)` in extended regex.

So I won't say `\b` and `\<` are the same. I'd say `\b` is a superset of `\<`. Vice versa for `\b` and `\>`.

Comment: Yes but can you give a practical example where it makes a difference?  Is there any regex (and text for it to match) where you'd get a different result by using `\b` instead of `\<` or `\>`?

Comment: @iconoclast Somebody should have answered this long ago.  It will make a difference if you don't have word/non-word characters around it.  `sed 's/\>/#/g'` won't do the same thing as `sed 's/\b/#/g'`.  If you have a non-word or a word character (or a class that is unambigously one of them) right next to the boundary match, they will unambiguously have the same behavior.

Comment: @Taywee iconoclast did [answer their own question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25491198/1743811) 3 years ago.

Comment: Bit of perl (e.g. `psed`) translate as follows: `\<` → `\b(?<=\W)` and `\>` → `\b(?=\W)`

Answer (score 4):

I stumbled upon such an example earlier. 
\<.\> matches a one letter word. 
Using \b you would need to put something like \b[^ ]\b, because \b.\b matches a space between two words.

Answer (score 1):

According to [LinuxTopia](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/linux_tool_guides/the_sed_faq/sedfaq6_009.html) the only difference between the two type of word boundaries is that whilst `\<` and `\>` work in most sed versions; the latter `\b` works only if your system is using **gsed**

And a quotation from the wiki:

> These symbols include '\<' and '>' (gsed, ssed, sed15, sed16, sedmod) and '\b' and '\B' (gsed only).

Other than that the two are identical.
Also here is a table that explains all possible scenarios that use word boundaries:

```
  Match position      Possible word boundaries   HHsed   GNU sed
  ---------------------------------------------------------------
  start of word    [nonword char]^[word char]      \<    \< or \b
  end of word         [word char]^[nonword char]   \>    \> or \b
  middle of word      [word char]^[word char]     none      \B
  outside of word  [nonword char]^[nonword char]  none      \B
  ---------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I don't think the questioner is concerned with which versions of sed support which conventions.  His version seems to support both, and his question seems to be about whether it makes any practical difference whether you use one or the other.