# How to append string in the contents of files on the basis of search

Tags: linux, unix

So far i have tried below unix script to append the contents of files on the basis of search. Everything is fine. But if i run the same below script multiple times the perl command is keep on appending in the files.

```
searchArr=(test1 test2 test3)

replaceArr=(somestring1 somestring2 somestring3) 

a=`echo ${#searchArr[@]}`
echo $a
for ((i=0;i<$a;i++))
do
searchValue=`echo ${searchArr[i]}`
replaceValue=`echo ${replaceArr[i]}`
for file in `find . -name \* -print`; do
  grep "$searchValue" $file &> /dev/null
  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "Search string not found in $file!"
  else
   perl -p -i -e "s/$searchValue/$replaceValue/g" $file
    echo $file "Replace string Success!"
  fi  
done
done
```

Current Output:-

If run more than one  times it will keep on appending like that.
For Example if run two times it will append two times

```
somestring1somestring1test1
somestring2somestring2test2
somestring3somestring3test3
```

Needed Output:-
No matter how many times it runs

```
somestring1test1
somestring2test2
somestring3test3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add word boundaries to your sed search pattern.

[Beginning and end of words in sed and grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382272/beginning-and-end-of-words-in-sed-and-grep)