# sed not working for special characters

Tags: regex, sed

I am trying to replace text using sed at word boundaries. After looking at [Beginning and end of words in sed and grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382272/beginning-and-end-of-words-in-sed-and-grep), I use:

```
echo "It is a @ at a@ ." | sed "s/\ba\b/#/g"
```

Output: It is **#** @ at a@ .

which works perfectly, but when I try to replace words which begin or end in special characters like @, it does not work.

```
echo "It is a @ at a@ ." | sed "s/\b@\b/#/g"
```

Output: It is a **@** at a@ .

```
echo "It is a @ at a@ ." | sed "s/\ba@\b/#/g"
```

Output: It is a @ at **a@** .

I am missing something ? How can I replace whole words that end in special characters using sed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `\B`

```
$ echo "It is a @ at a@ ." | sed "s/\B@\B/#/g"
It is a # at a@ .
```

`\b` - matches between a word char and non-word char (vice-versa)

`\B` - matches between two word chars or two non-word chars.

So the char exists before `@` is space which is a non-word character. So to match the boundary which exists between two non-word chars, you need to use `\B` and the character exists after `@` is also the space character. So here, you need to use `\B` also.

For the second case, you have to use this,

```
$ echo "It is a @ at a@ ." | sed "s/\ba@\B/#/g"
It is a @ at # .
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/OMJkYa)