# Add prefix to each word of each line in bash

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have a variable called deps:

```
deps='word1 word2'
```

I want to add a prefix to each word of the variable.

I tried with:

```
echo $deps | while read word do \ echo "prefix-$word" \ done
```

but i get:

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `done'

any help? thanks

Comment: so you want the output to be `prefix-word1 prefix-word2`, right?

Comment: you need semi colons, not that it will work with them, but it would stop the error.

Comment: `for i in $deps;do echo "prefix-$i";done`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

With sed :

```
$ deps='word1 word2'
$ echo "$deps" | sed 's/[^ ]* */prefix-&/g'
prefix-word1 prefix-word2
```

Comment: Perhaps simpler: `echo $deps | sed 's/\</prefix-/g'`

Comment: @Nasorenga Yes but it is worth noting that `\<` and `\>` are a GNU syntax, so less portable.

Comment: when deps is blank, how to avoid the transformation without an if statement?

Comment: @techguy2000 Try to add an address(`/^$/!`) to apply the `s` command to non-empty lines only: `echo "$deps" | sed '/^$/!s/[^ ]* */prefix-&/g'`

Answer (score 21):

For well behaved strings, the best answer is:

```
printf "prefix-%s\n" $deps
```

as suggested by 123 in the comments to fedorqui's answer.

Explanation:

- Without quoting, bash will split the contents of `$deps` according to `$IFS` (which defaults to `" \n\t"`) before calling `printf`
- `printf` evaluates the pattern for each of the provided arguments and writes the output to stdout.
- `printf` is a shell built-in (at least for bash) and does not fork another process, so this is faster than sed-based solutions.

Answer (score 3):

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382272/beginning-and-end-of-words-in-sed-and-grep) I just came across the markers for beginning (`\<`) and end (`\>`) of words. With those you can shorten the solution of [SLePort](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38263355/671366) above somewhat. The solution also nicely extends to appending a suffix, which I needed in addition to the prefix, but couldn't figure out how to use above solution for it, as the `&` also includes the possible trailing whitespace after the word.

So my solution is this:

```
$ deps='word1 word2'

# add prefix:
$ echo "$deps" | sed 's/\</prefix-/g'
prefix-word1 prefix-word2

# add suffix:
$ echo "$deps" | sed 's/\>/-suffix/g'
word1-suffix word2-suffix
```

**Explanation:** `\<` matches the beginning of every word, and `\>` matches the end of each word. You can simply "replace" these by the prefix/suffix, resulting in them being prepended/appended. There is no need to reference them anymore in the replacement, as these are not "real" characters anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can read the string into an array and then prepend the string to every item:

```
$ IFS=' ' read -r -a myarray <<< "word1 word2"
$ printf "%s\n" "${myarray[@]}"
word1
word2
$ printf "prefix-%s\n" "${myarray[@]}"
prefix-word1
prefix-word2
```

Comment: You could also use the original string instead of an array `printf "prefix-%s\n" $deps`