# Replace single character, dash, in a tab delimited text file

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am running windows with GNU bash, version 4.3.46(2)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)

**Reproducible Example**

- I have a large tab delimited text file, with many lines and columns. This is just an example of what the data format is

  ```
  echo -e 'Test-123\tA\tA\tC\t-\t-\tT\tG\t'
  Test-123        A       A       C       -       -       T       G
  ```

**Problem**

- I want to only replace the - character with N. If the name of the line contains a dash I need to keep it that way.
- Example of the output file I want:

  ```
  Test-123        A       A       C       N       N       T       G
  ```

**Solutions I tried**

- I tried escaping the - using sed

  ```
  sed -e 's,\<-\>,N,g'
  ```
- It did not work, I checked the character count before and after and they were the same

  ```
  tr -cd - < test2_chr01.txt | wc -c
  ```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: @anubhava your answer doesn't work. It removes the - in the Test-123. I need to preserve that dash

Comment: What is wrong with `sed -e 's/\t-/\tN/g'` ?  All the answers here are so complicated that I must be missing something.

Comment: @stevesliva put your comment as an answer, I tried it and it worked. I will accept your answer as it is the simplest and works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed -e 's/\t-/\tN/g'`

The dash doesn't need escaping unless used within square brackets as far as I know.

This simply assumes that only the first column should not have tab-dash replaced, and it works just fine for the last column.

Answer (score 2):

Another awk:

```
$ a='Test-123\tA\tA\tC\t-\t-\tT\tG\t' 
$ echo -e $a | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i=="-")$i="N"}1'
Test-123        A       A       C       N       N       T       G
```

Explained:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }   # delimiters
{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)  # for each field
        if($i=="-")     # if a single dash
            $i="N"      # overwrite it
}1'                     # output
```

**Edit**: If you are looking for a `sed`solution:

```
$ echo -e $a | sed -e 's/\B-\B/N/g' 
Test-123        A       A       C       N       N       T       G
```

Apparently `\B` works on GNU sed only ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17382369/4162356))

Another **edit**: Using perl and lookahead. We replace `\t-` with `\tN` if the former is followed by a `\ţ`. That way we can avoid overlapping regions:

```
$ echo -e $a | perl -ne 's/\t-(?=\t)/\tN/g; print'
Test-123        A       A       C       N       N       T       G
```

Comment: Added `sed` solution.

Comment: I think the `awk` one is most robust... it is field based on tabs and only changes fields if it matches `-`... the `GNU sed` might work for OP's case, but would fail if there can be spaces in fields or if field is like `-;`

Comment: @Sundeep Probably.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo -e 'Test-123\tA\tA\tC\t-\t-\tT\tG\t'|sed 's/\B-\B/N/g'
```

Comment: would fail if there can be spaces in fields or if field is like `-;`

Comment: @Sundeep     echo -e 'Test-123\tA\tA\tC\t-\t-;\tT\tG\t'|sed 's/\B-\S*\B/N/g'   ?

Comment: well the point was it shouldn't replace fields like `-;` or `a - b` because field separator is `tab` and only entire field matching `-` should be replaced... that said, `sed 's/\B-\B/N/g'` might well work for OP's case

Answer (score 0):

***awk*** solution:

```
echo -e 'Test-123\tA\tA\tC\t-\t-\tT\tG\t' | awk -v OFS='\t' '{ for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) sub("-","N",$i) }1'
```

The output:

```
Test-123        A       A       C       N       N       T       G
```

Comment: If the first field is a dash, your script fails

Comment: @Aserre, that moment "if the 1st field is just a `-`" was not mentioned in the question

Comment: In the case of my data, the first field will never be a -, but it is a good point for others trying to use this answer for some other application.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`echo -e 'Test-123\tA\tA\tC\t-\t-\tT\tG\t' | sed -e 's/\([[:space:]]\)-\{1,\}/\1N/g'`

Comment: Dan Krieger - did you test that? It doesn't work. I need to preserve the dash in the Test-123, your solution removes that dash as well.

Comment: @MattD I just updated it. This works by capturing the whitespace and storing it as \1.

Comment: @MattD

`echo -e 'Test-123\tA\tA\tC\t-\t-\tT\tG\t' | sed -e 's/\([[:space:]]\)-\{1,\}/\1N/g'`


I've updated it above as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a `sed` solution then following should work with `gnu sed`:

```
echo -e 'Test-123\tA\tA\tC\t-\t-\tT\tG\t' | sed ':a;s/\t-\t/\tN\t/g;ta;'
Test-123    A   A   C   N   N   T   G
```

If you don't have `gnu sed` then use:

```
echo -e 'Test-123\tA\tA\tC\t-\t-\tT\tG\t' | sed -e ':a' -e $'s/\\\t-\\\t/\\\tN\\\t/g;ta'
Test-123    A   A   C   N   N   T   G
```

If you have `perl` command line then use this look around based regex:

```
echo -e 'Test-123\tA\tA\tC\t-\t-\tT\tG\t' | perl -pe 's/(?<=\s)-(?=\s)/N/g'
Test-123    A   A   C   N   N   T   G
```

Comment: both solutions won't replace if first column is `-`.. the perl one is easy to modify: `perl -pe 's/(\s|^)\K-(?=\s)/N/g'`

Comment: Most likely that's what OP wants, if not then it can be easily updated to take care of start and end e.g. `perl -pe 's/(^|\s)\K-(?=\s|$)/N/g'`

Comment: yeah likely will meet what OP wants... but I wonder if OP has spaces in any column data

Comment: No spaces, data has been cleaned prior to my use, only contains 12 or so possible characters that the non-row names can have. Row names have no spaces. I don't want to change anything with the row name.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you want to replace any occurence of `\t-\t` (minus as only character in field) with `\tN\n`. The problem here is that 2 adjacent `-` fields will overlap so `sed -e 's/\t-\t/\tN\t/g` will not be enough.

You have to use a true script say it is file sedscript:

```
:top
s/\t-\t/\tN\t/
t top
```

(real tabs have been noted \t here but should be real tabs in file)

The script means:

- `:top`            : simple label
- `s/\t-\t/\tN\t/`  : replace one single occurence of "tab - tab" with "tab N tab"
- `t top`           : if a replacement occur loop, else print the replaced line and iterate to next one

You use it that way:

```
$ echo -e 'Test-123\tA\tA\tC\t-\t-\tT\tG\t' | sed -f sedscript
Test-123        A       A       C       N       N       T       G
```

If you do not want to use a external script, you can pass the commands one at a time with -e:

```
$ echo -e 'Test-123\tA\tA\tC\t-\t-\tT\tG\t' | sed -e ':a' -e $'s/\\\t-\\\t/\\\tN\\\t/g' -e 'ta'
Test-123        A       A       C       N       N       T       G
```